# entity in external xml dtd

Tags: html, xml, dtd-parsing, dtd

I am trying to put **ENTITY** in externaL **DTD** file but its not showing values of **ENTITY** in **XML** when it is parsed.

But its working when I combine the **XML** and **DTD** in one file below is my code for **XML** and **DTD**

**info.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE info SYSTEM "./Note.dtd">  <info>   
<info>
<company>&company_info;</company>   
<privacy_policy>&privacy_policy;</privacy_policy>  </info>
</info>
```

**Note.dtd**

```
<!ENTITY company_info "<name>Test Company</name><location>Berlin</location><phone>1800-000-000</phone>">
<!ENTITY privacy_policy "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, .">
```

**info.xml** and **Note.dtd** is in same folder

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're using to parse the XML, but I know Xerces will throw errors about `<info>` not being declared if you use the file extension ".dtd".

Try changing "Note.dtd" to "Note.ent".

I did this with your sample files and the errors went away. Also, I was able to do an identity transform using Saxon on your original info.xml and the entity references were resolved without error.

Comment: Currently I tried to open XML directly in browser firefox & safari but I am getting error in both browsers.

My main aim is to convert XML into json using JSON-LIB available at 
http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @AnupSingh - Firefox (and safari) won't load external DTDs or external entities. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XML_in_Mozilla#DTDs_and_Other_External_Entities

Comment: ah!.. hard luck.. Thanks for response.. 

can you please suggest me that "what is the preferred way to convert XML to JSON that resolves external entity references".

Comment: @AnupSingh - Sorry, I don't have any experience with JSON. That would be a great new question though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p>
i had the same problem..just use php instead

<?php
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
// code injection from the client side
$file='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE login SYSTEM "http://localhost/e.ent">
<login><user>&name;</user><pass>password</pass></login>';
//
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($file,LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_DTDLOAD);
$element=$dom->getElementsByTagName('user')[0];
echo $element->nodeValue;
?></p>
```

Comment: check my github repository https://github.com/UnknownAD/xml_injection/blob/master/demo.php